# creating nodes in Neo4j using neo4j python driver not working

Tags: python, neo4j

I have a problem when creating node in Neo4j

```
   path_data = "BPI2000sample.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path_data)
uri= "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri,auth=("neo4j","123456"))
session = driver.session()
def create_contsraint(tx):
    tx.run("use loan1 CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (e:Event) ASSERT e.name IS UNIQUE;")
    tx.run("use loan1 CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (c:Case) ASSERT c.name IS UNIQUE;")
    tx.run("use loan1 CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (r:Resource) ASSERT r.name IS UNIQUE;")

session.write_transaction(create_contsraint)

with session.begin_transaction() as tx:
    for row in df[df.case.unique == cases].iterrows():
         j = j + 1
         msg = tx.run("use loan1  MERGE (c:Case {name: $case})", case= row[0])
         print(msg)
         #msg = tx.run("use loan1  MERGE (c:Case {name: $case})", case=row[0])
        #row = cursor.fetchone()
    tx.success = True  # commit the cypher statements

print("total nodes created:",j)
```

It write the constraints but didn't create nodes what is the problem here?

Comment: Pls give us sample csv file. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the message received?
I would suspect that you can't use `:use loan1` to define the database, it is usually set at the session level:

```
session = driver.session(database="loan1")
```

And then:

```
msg = tx.run("MERGE (c:Case {name: $case})", case= row[0])
```